# Text with image in jssor

Tags: javascript, slider, jssor

Good day, reader,
I'm having a trouble with jssor slider.

The problem is that only img is shown. And the button is hidden. And only when I try to find it using ctrl+f, it is displayed.
Here is my code

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1000px; height: 400px; overflow: hidden; ">

    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
                    background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
                    top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Slides Container -->

            <div u="caption" style="display:block; position: absolute; top: 300px; width: 235px;height: 100px;">Your lips<div class="btn">Получить консультацию</div></div></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="../img/ancient-lady/006.jpg" />
            <div u="caption" style="display:block; position: absolute; top: 300px; width: 235px;height: 100px;">Your tie<div class="btn">Получить консультацию</div></div></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="../img/ancient-lady/011.jpg" />
            <div u="caption" style="display:block; position: absolute; top: 300px; width: 235px;height: 100px;">I'm sick of<div class="btn">Получить консультацию</div></div></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="../img/ancient-lady/013.jpg" />
            <div u="caption" style="display:block; position: absolute; top: 300px; width: 235px;height: 100px;">50 cent P.I.M.P<div class="btn">Получить консультацию</div></div></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="../img/ancient-lady/014.jpg" />
            <div u="caption" style="display:block; position: absolute; top: 300px; width: 235px;height: 100px;">Gosh!<div class="btn">Получить консультацию</div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! Yupii!

First of all I set height of the slide in options:`$SlideHeight: n`

And made correction in u="slides" style:`height:(n+k)px`

And last thing: I selected my outer divs for every slide and added that line to style css:

```
overflow: visible !important;
```